# How to initialize SQLXML with Document object in Java

Tags: hibernate, jpa, sqlxml

How do I convert a `org.w3c.dom.Document` object to `java.sql.SQLXML` so that it can be persisted into the database using Hibernate? Currently I can get it to work by converting it to a String via `javax.xml.transform.Transformer`, but I imagine it is the least efficient approach.

I have tried the following but nothing got saved into the DB column.

```
SQLXML sqlxml = session.connection().createSQLXML();
sqlxml.setResult(DOMResult.class).setNode(myDocument);
preparedStmt.setSQLXML(index, sqlxml);
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it is not working as intended, just use `javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXResult` instead to make it work:

```
SQLXML sqlxml = stmt.getConnection().createSQLXML();
SAXResult sax = sqlxml.setResult(SAXResult.class);
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), sax);
stmt.setSQLXML(index, sqlxml);
```

Comment: Surely using SAX isn't necessary?